# C# lambda operator for assignment

Tags: c#, lambda, properties, syntactic-sugar

I came across this in our code-base today, and it took me awhile to see what the effect of it was, but what in the world does this actually mean??

```
public virtual SomeClass InstanceVariable => new SomeClass("arg1", "arg2");
```

I played around with this in Visual Studio's C# interactive terminal and discovered that it appears to be equivalent to:

```
public virtual SomeClass InstanceVariable { get { new SomeClass("arg1", "arg2"); } }
```

However, I couldn't find any documentation on this being any form of 'syntactic sugar' for a read-only property.

Someone want to shed some light on the scenario?

Comment: It's C# 6.0, take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx

Comment: I'd say this is more readable source https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is from new C# 6.0. You can instantiate your class by default. Check "Expression Bodied Functions and Properties" of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx article